# How to add a line at the below of xAxis in Highcharts?

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng

I want to add a line at the below of xAxis in Highcharts.
I can't find any options for this issue.
Could you please let me know how to add the line?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no option in the API to set a bottom line for the axis, but you can use the `chart.events.render()` callback function to duplicate the default line.

**Demo**: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/z9jd8p5h/ 
**API**: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render